# Activating knockout bindings to specific part of document

Tags: knockout.js

Consider this code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var menuView = function() {
            var self = this;
            this.blancos = ko.observableArray([]);

            this.load_blancos = function() {
                $.getJSON("{% url api_template_list_create %}", function (data) {
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.blancos);
                })
            };

            this.init = function() {
                self.load_blancos();
            };

            this.init();
        };

        ko.applyBindings(new menuView(), document.getElementById('blancos_menu'));
    });
```

And this HTML:

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="blancos_menu">
    <li><a href="{% url template_planning %}">Create new</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <span data-bind="text: $root.blancos"></span>
    <!-- ko foreach: $root.blancos -->
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-bind="text:name"></a>
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
```

The ko: foreach function does not execute (i.e. no list items generated). I do see "[object Object],[object Object]" in the preceding span (there for testing purposes).

For a very bizarre reason, when I change the line `<span data-bind="text: $root.blancos"></span>` to `<span data-bind="text: blancos"></span>`, the ko: foreach function is executed and I get to see the different list items.

Surprisingly I do get a JavasScript error stating that blancos is not defined and hence cannot be bound. (BUT! The span still contains the text "[object Object],[object Object]").

I really can't get my around it; thanks for looking into this.

By the way, the data returned by the JSON call is:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "123"}, {"id": 2, "name": "test_wzzob"}]
```

**UPDATE**

Changing

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
```

into

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.blancos);
```

does the trick indeed, but there's still an error

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: blancos is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach: blancos
```

The same applies for other properties or methods. I *dont't* get that error when prepending the variables (or functions) I'm binding in the HTML with $root (but then, they're empty).

Answer (score 1):

Docs say:

```
// Every time data is received from the server:
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
```

but you supplies observableArray instead of View Model:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.blancos);
```

Try this way:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS({ blancos: data }, {}, self);
```

Comment: Aha, thanks for spotting that one! The list items are being generated now. I'm still getting an "Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: blancos is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach: blancos" though, preventing the rest of my KO script (another viewmodel) to load correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you just use blancos, rather than $root.blancos? You shouldn't need the root, as blancos is a property of the view model that you are binding to that part of the page:

```
<li data-bind="foreach: blancos">
    <a href="#" data-bind="text:name"></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ko.applyBindings(new menuView(), document.getElementById('blancos_menu'));
```

replace this with

```
ko.applyBindings(new menuView(),$("#blancos_menu")[0]);
```

and why you using this?

```
<span data-bind="text: $root.blancos"></span>
    <!-- ko foreach: $root.blancos -->
```

you can use

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: blancos">
<li data-bind="<ARRAY ELEMENT IN blancos>"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I thought that those two ways of getting an element were the same.

Comment: That would make no difference.

Comment: Indeed, using jQuery does not make a difference.

Comment: Also, I'm using the <!-- bit because there are ul's above and below the one generated by the blancos array.